# Defining protocols in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

What are the differences between these three protocol definitions in Swift?

1. `protocol FooDelegate {}`
2. `@objc protocol FooDelegate {}` -- is this the same as `protocol FooDelegate, NSObjectProtocol {}`?
3. `protocol FooDelegate: class {}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll deal with the cases in a slightly different order:

1. A protocol can be adopted by an enum, a struct, or a class.
2. `protocol FooDelegate: class {}` means that *this* protocol can be adopted only by a class.
3. `@objc protocol FooDelegate {}` exposes this protocol to Objective-C - Objective-C can "see" it. It also implies (2), i.e. now this is a class protocol.

A good example of why you'd want to do (2) is when you want to declare a weak instance property typed as a protocol:

```
weak var delegate : MyDelegateProtocol
```

You can't say `weak` unless this thing is a *class* instance - not a struct or enum (since they do not have the same memory management). Declaring this protocol as a class protocol calms the fears of the compiler by telling it that whoever adopts this protocol *will* in fact be a class.

A good example of why you'd want to do (3) is that you want your protocol to have optional members. Only Objective-C can do that, so you effectively turn your protocol into an Objective-C protocol. And of course protocols *defined* in Objective-C are automatically seen by Swift as `@objc` protocols.

Comment: And see my new Swift tutorial: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_optional_protocol_members

Answer (score 1):

To add to matt's answer,

> @objc protocol FooDelegate {} -- is this the same as protocol
>   FooDelegate, NSObjectProtocol {}?

You mean `protocol FooDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {}`? No. It doesn't extend `NSObjectProtocol` unless you explicitly declare it as such.